# Using "@" in key when inserting to MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose schema won't let me use @ sign in key when inserting to MongoDB with using Node.js. For instance:

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
@context : Object //error illegal token
@id : String // illegal token


}, {strict: false});
```

I tried key with unicode characters like this one:

```
"\u0040context" = Object // ignored unicode, inserted as context
 "\x40context" = Object // ignored unicode, inserted as context
 \x40context = Object // illegal token
```

Also tried with normal way using this link(first way), still cannot define key with @:
http://blog.modulus.io/mongodb-tutorial

My purpose is to create document with using JSON-LD format which requires of using @ symbol in key. How to accomplish this? Here are the similar links I have looked for solution:
[variable with mongodb dotnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702450/variable-with-mongodb-dotnotation)
[Syntax error Unexpected token ILLEGAL Mongo Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299482/syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal-mongo-console)
[How to use mongoose model schema with dynamic keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228599/how-to-use-mongoose-model-schema-with-dynamic-keys)
[How to do a query using dot( . ) through Mongoose in Node.js and How to add an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744761/how-to-do-a-query-using-dot-through-mongoose-in-node-js-and-how-to-add-an-e)
[Create a Schema object in Mongoose/Handlebars with custom keys/values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891479/create-a-schema-object-in-mongoose-handlebars-with-custom-keys-values)
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directly `@` between quotes such as `"@field"` :

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require('./node_modules/mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connection;

var itemSchema = new Schema({
    "@field": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "@field2": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
var Items = mongoose.model('Items', itemSchema);

var db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'testDB');

Items.create({ "@field": "value", "@field2": "value" }, function(err, doc) {
    console.log("created");
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log(doc);
    }
    db.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: oh thanks for your time and detailed answer, worked like a charm.